# SQL Case Statement with SUM Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know there must be some question like me. Seems I cannot find the question, I sorry to ask this question.

Below is my table (SalesTransaction)

```
ID   |SalesID   |Amount   |AmountReceived |OutStanding |Paid
2041  1000       600000    600000          0            1
2042  1000       1500000   2000000        -500000       1
2043  1000       900000    0               900000       0
2047  1002       300000    0               300000       0
```

Using SQL Query below:

```
SELECT ID, 
       SalesID, 
       Amount, 
       AmountReceived, 
       OutStanding, 
       Paid, 
       (CASE 
          WHEN Paid = 0 THEN (SELECT SUM(OutStanding) 
                              FROM SalesTransaction 
                              WHERE Paid = 1 ) 
        ELSE 0 END) AS BalanceLastSchedule 
FROM dbo.SalesTransaction 
GROUP BY ID, SalesID, Amount, AmountReceived, OutStanding, Paid
```

I get result like below:

```
ID   |SalesID   |Amount   |AmountReceived |OutStanding |Paid |BalanceLastSch
2041  1000       600000    600000          0            1     0.00
2042  1000       1500000   2000000        -500000       1     0.00
2043  1000       900000    0               900000       0     -500000
2047  1002       300000    0               300000       0     -500000
```

What I want to get like below:

```
ID   |SalesID   |Amount   |AmountReceived |OutStanding |Paid |BalanceLastSch
2041  1000       600000    600000          0            1     0.00
2042  1000       1500000   2000000        -500000       1     0.00
2043  1000       900000    0               900000       0     -500000
2047  1002       300000    0               300000       0     0.00
```

Appreciate I get help on this. Thanks.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: You can delete your own questions.

Comment: You can edit  as well

Comment: Thanks TheGameiswar, I already edit my table. Thanks again.

Comment: I using MS SQL. Thanks.

Comment: would you mind create a demo in http://sqlfiddle.com/? Since the `BalanceLastSch` can not have these values for the data. And also: why `BalanceLastSch` should be zero in the last column?

Comment: The expected result doesn't make sense. You write in your query, that in case of Paid = 0 the sum(Outstanding) of all records with Paid = 1 should be taken... so the result you get (-5.0000 for the last two rows) is "as designed". Could you please explain, what you expect instead of simpy putting the expected results? what should be calculated in case Paid is 0 and what if Paif is 1?

Comment: This query been design in my view so I can showed the data in my project design apps (using ID = ID). BalanceLastSch should be zero in the last column (ID 2047) because the SalesID is 1002. While the others 3 data is SalesID = 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the wrong answer because you have not joined the Inner Query to find the sum with the SalesId. try this below script

```
SELECT
  SeqNo, 
 SalesID, 
 Amount, 
 AmountReceived, 
 OutStanding, 
 Paid,
 ISNULL((CASE 
          WHEN Paid = 0 THEN (SELECT SUM(OutStanding) 
                              FROM SalesTransaction 
                              WHERE Paid = 1
                                AND SalesId = T.SalesId) 
        ELSE 0 END),0.00) AS BalanceLastSchedule 
  FROM SalesTransaction T;
```

i just added the below setion inside tour inner query and removed the group By Clause

```
AND SalesId = T.SalesId
```

Comment: Wow!! Thanks. Seems I miss on that. Last I tried, I just make SalesID = SalesID and it not work. Thanks again Jayasurya Satheesh. :)